# Max records count we can show in HTML Table in one go

Tags: angular, html, html-table

I am trying to present 100k+ rows in a HTML table in one go, but page was not responding, at the same time I am presenting same records with pivot js as a Pivot without any issue how could it possible? am I missing any basic points?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Angular try to add all data one by one and Angular's ChangeDetectRef bind and unbind took place sequentially. Thus it takes to much time for it to load. you need something VirtualScroll or Ngx-infintySCroll

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way pivot.js designed is to handle large data set which is formated , there are logic implementation to group data so that it stores only the summarized data.

But when you are loading dataset on your own it stores the data on client without being 
grouped/summarized. Maximum browsers can handle upto 10k records.

When it comes to pivot js it can handle upto 200k rows as mentioned [`here`](https://github.com/nicolaskruchten/pivottable/issues/36)